# Why do some commands not work inside TMUX?

Tags: rust, zsh, tmux, rust-cargo

When I type `cargo` (that is a Rust build system and package manager) inside tmux, the terminal shows:

```
zsh: command not found: cargo
```

Outside of tmux, I have this output:

```
$ which cargo
/home/slacksenick/.cargo/bin/cargo
$ echo $PATH
/home/slacksenick/.cargo/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/lib64/qt/bin:/usr/share/texmf/bin
```

Inside of tmux:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/lib64/qt/bin:/usr/share/texmf/bin
```

I've tried to configure the .tmux.conf, but keep getting the error.
On every site, the unix errors are about key bindings and nothing similar to this.

My tmux.conf:

```
# Set bind key to reload configuration
bind r source-file ~/.tmux.conf \; display "Reloaded!"

set -g status-style fg=green, bg=black
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: If you type cargo _outside_ of tmux, does it work? If so, what's the output of `which cargo` and `echo $PATH` outside of tmux, and of `echo $PATH` inside of tmux?

Comment: What platform are you on?

Comment: i'm in Slackware Linux 14.2.

Comment: Have you edited your `$PATH` at all since installing Cargo? If so, have you logged out and logged back in since doing that? And what are the answers to the questions Sven already asked?

Comment: ```which cargo > /home/slacksenick/.cargo/bin/cargo
```  ```echo $PATH                                               slacksenick@senick
/home/slacksenick/.cargo/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/lib64/qt/bin:/usr/share/texmf/bin```

Comment: outside tmux i have this outpus.

Comment: echo $PATH inside tmux: ```/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/lib64/qt/bin:/usr/share/texmf/bin```

Comment: yees i modified the $PATH, i'll try reverse the process and try again.

Comment: If you have edited your `PATH` since starting `tmux`, those changes aren't automatically inherited by shells already running in a `tmux` session.

Comment: How did you modify $PATH? If you just set it within the current shell session (`PATH=...`), it won't be propagated to child processes. If you set it with `export`, it will also be set within child processes that are not login shells (I'm not sure what kind of shell tmux starts by default) but not by new processes that are not children. If you put it in `.zshenv` or `.zshrc` it should be set in all new interactive shells whether they are in tmux or not.

Comment: @MichelAngelo : I assume that you set up your `PATH` in either `~/.zshrc` or in `~/.zshenv`. So, if you are inside your tmux shell and your PATH is wrong, and you open a zsh subshell explicitly, the PATH should then be correct, isn't it?

Comment: when i assigned the $PATH showed outside of tmux to $PATH inside tmux, the tmux recognized the ```cargo````command, now i've to set it's in .zshrc?

Comment: @user1934428 yes this worked, :)

Comment: but how put i the right $PATH in .zshrc or .zshenv ? the right PATH is ```/home/slacksenick/.cargo/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/lib64/qt/bin:/usr/share/texmf/bin```

Comment: Typically, to add a path to `$PATH` you would add a line like `export PATH=/home/slacksenick/.cargo/bin:$PATH` to `.zshenv` ([see here for differences between the various rc-files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71253/what-should-shouldnt-go-in-zshenv-zshrc-zlogin-zprofile-zlogout)). This way you don't override any systemwide modifications to `$PATH` (such as those in `/etc/profile`) by setting it to a static list of paths.

Comment: IIS WORKINGG, thanks everyone <3 <3, i love you.

Answer (score 1):

you can try to  add this :`. "$HOME/.cargo/env"`  in your `.bashrc` or your `.zshrc` file. it works for me.